# How to find invariance in 4 groups?

Tags: r, grouping

I used this code to find differences between genders age groups:

```
    GeneralModel.fit = cfa(model = GeneralModel,
                           data=Invariance,
                           meanstructure = TRUE)

summary(GeneralModel.fit,
        standardized=TRUE,
        rsquare=TRUE,
        fit.measure = TRUE)

parameterestimates(GeneralModel.fit, standardized=TRUE)
fitted(GeneralModel.fit)
residuals(GeneralModel.fit)
fitmeasures(GeneralModel.fit)
modificationindices(GeneralModel.fit)

semPaths(GeneralModel.fit,
         whatLabels = "std",
         layout = "tree")

Teenagers = subset(Invariance, Group == "0")

Teenagers.fit = cfa(GeneralModel,
                     data=Teenagers,
                     meanstructure=TRUE)
summary(Teenagers.fit,
        standardized=TRUE,
        rsquare=TRUE,
        fit.measure=TRUE)

parameterestimates(Teenagers.fit, standardized = TRUE)
fitted(Teenagers.fit)
residuals(Teenagers.fit)
fitmeasures(Teenagers.fit)

semPaths(Teenagers.fit,
         whatLabels = "std",
         layout = "tree")

CollegesStudents = subset(Invariance, Group == "1")
CollegeStudents
CollegeStudents.fit = cfa(GeneralModel,
                     data=CollegeStudents,
                     meanstructure=TRUE)
summary(CollegeStudents.fit,
        standardized=TRUE,
        rsquare=TRUE,
        fit.measure=TRUE)

parameterestimates(CollegeStudents.fit, standardized = TRUE)
fitted(CollegeStudents.fit)
residuals(CollegeStudents.fit)
fitmeasures(CollegeStudents.fit)
IM <- measurementInvariance(model=GeneralModel, data=Invariance, group="Group")
```

For gender differences, I used this same method (with different names, of course).

Now the question:

How can this script be changed to find invariance on four groups (teen women, teen men, college women, and college men)? Do I have to specify with the codes `Group1="Sex"` and `Group2="Age Group"` when creating the subsets, such as:

- teen women being: `Group1 == 0`, `Group2 == 0`
- teen men being: `Group1 == 1`, `Group2 == 0`,
- college women being: `Group1 == 0, Group2 == 1`
- and college men being `Group1 == 1, Group2 == 1`?

I do not know if I answered my own question with this, so I would like to confirm whether it was wrong or not and if there are better ways to do what I seek to do. My gratitude in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider generalizing your process in a user-defined method and then use `by` to run various level of subsets that are passed into method. And since some subsets may return no rows, wrap method in `tryCatch` to safely return a `NULL` (empty result) upon error:

```
find_diffs <- function(df) {
    tryCatch({
        model_fit = cfa(model = GeneralModel,
                        data = df
                        meanstructure = TRUE)

        summary(model_fit,
                standardized=TRUE,
                rsquare=TRUE,
                fit.measure = TRUE)

        # NAMED LIST OF RESULTS
        results <- list(estimates = parameterestimates(model_fit, standardized=TRUE),
                        fit = fitted(model_fit),
                        residuals = residuals(model_fit),
                        fitmeasures = fitmeasures(model_fit),
                        mod_indices = modificationindices(model_fit)
                   )
        }, error = function(e) return(NULL)
    )
}
```

**NO `by`**

```
GeneralModel_fit <- find_diffs(Invariance)
# ALL RESULTS
GeneralModel_fit

# SELECT RESULTS
GeneralModel_fit$estimates
GeneralModel_fit$fit
GeneralModel_fit$residuals
...
```

**ONE `by` GROUP**

```
sex_fit_list <- by(Invariance, Invariance$Group1, find_diffs)

# WOMEN
sex_fit_list$`0`    
# MEN
sex_fit_list$`1`


age_fit_list <- by(Invariance, Invariance$Group2, find_diffs)

# TEENAGERS
age_fit_list$`0`    
# COLLEGE STUDENTS
age_fit_list$`1`
```

**TWO `by` GROUPS**

```
sex_and_age_fit_list <- by(Invariance, Invariance[,c("Group1", "Group2")], find_diffs)

# TEEN GIRLS
sex_and_age_fit_list[[1]]

# COLLEGE WOMEN
sex_and_age_fit_list[[2]]

# TEEN BOYS
sex_and_age_fit_list[[3]]

# COLLEGE MEN
sex_and_age_fit_list[[4]]
```